# I can't telnet to zabbix agent on port 10050. What could be the reason?

Tags: zabbix, ubuntu

Today i installed zabbix server and agent on 2 instance (ubuntu 16.04) on AWS
Here's the zabbix-agent configuration file

```
Server=IP-of-zabbix-server
ListenPort=10050
ServerActive=IP-of-zabbix-serve
```

I got this error: Zabbix agent on Zabbix Client 1 is unreachable for 5 minutes
I tried to telnet from zabbix server to zabbix agent but failed.
What could be the reasons for this?

Comment: I would check the following: Is the agent listening on port 10050? Is the service up? Is there any firewall? What the logs say?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio Turned out it was related to security group in AWS. Even though i opend all TCP port from 0 to 65535 but it didn't work. Finally, i decided to use default security group which opens all port, TCP, UDP etc. And it worked.